# SSH鍵の生成時にファイル名が文字化けを起こしてしまう

Tags: windows-10, openssh, git-bash

Git Bash をインストールして、[今日からはじめるGitHub](https://employment.en-japan.com/engineerhub/entry/2017/01/31/110000) の記事を参考にしつつ、GitHubで利用するための公開鍵・秘密鍵の生成を試しているのですが、鍵の入ったファイル名が入力通りになりません。

Git Bash に以下の通り入力して、鍵はちゃんと生成されています。

```
$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/UserName/.ssh/id_rsa):GitHub_id_rsa
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been id_rsainGitHub_id_rsa
Your public key has been id_rsainGitHub_id_rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:鍵の名前 UserName@DESKTOP-PVC6S7K
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
| .      .. .BoB=*|
|. . .   .. oo@o%+|
| . . . .  +. oOoX|
|  E   .    oo. B=|
|        S .  .=.B|
|         . . o.+.|
|            . .  |
|                 |
|                 |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

しかし、ファイル名を `GitHub_id_rsa` としているにも関わらず、実際に生成されたファイル名は画像のようになっています。

そもそも `.ssh/id_rsa` というディレクトリが作られていないのですが、自動で作られるわけではなく、手動で作る必要があるのでしょうか？
(参考記事内では手動でファイルを作成するような記述はありませんでした)

**生成された鍵ファイル:**
[image: 鍵の生成が上手くいかない]

どのようにすれば指定した名前の鍵ファイルを生成できるのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

環境:Windows10

Comment: ファイル名の変更は後からエクスプローラ上での操作でも可能なので、`ssh-keygen` で試しにデフォルトのまま進めるとどうなりますか。

Comment: @tetris `.ssh` というディレクトリはありますか？

Comment: @cubick ありがとうございます。デフォルトのまま進めると上手くいきました。sshファイルが作成およびid_rsaファイルとid_rsa.pubファイルが作成されました。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 質問を投稿した時点では生成されていませんでした。コメントでご指摘いただいた通りデフォルトでやってみると上手くいきました

Comment: 作業している Windows アカウントのユーザ名に日本語は含まれていますか？ / デフォルトのままで進める方法でも OK なようであれば、一つの回答として投稿し直しておきます。

Comment: @cubick 含まれています。日本語が含まれているのが正しく生成されなかった原因でしょうか？デフォルトのまま進める方法でOKです！ありがとうございます。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

恐らく Windows のアカウント名に日本語が含まれているのが原因ではないかと思われます。

鍵ファイルは後からエクスプローラの操作でも名前を変更できるので、`ssh-keygen` 実行時に鍵ファイル名は指定せずにデフォルトのまま作成できるかを試してみてください。

もしくは `ssh-keygen` 実行時に `-f` オプションで作成する鍵ファイルを指定できるので、日本語を含まない (かつアクセスが許可された) フォルダ以下を代わりに指定する方法もあります。

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /c/TEMP/id_rsa
```